# set color for placeholder string

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

is there any way to set color to a text box placeholder

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col col-50">
        <input type="number" placeholder="Price Color" name="price" class="textbox" ng-model="Price"required>
    </div>    
    <div class="col col-50">
        <input type="number" placeholder="Discount Color" class="textbox" ng-model="discount">
    </div>    
</div>
```

i want to change the color inside the text box placeholder that is "Price Color"  and "Discount Color" this string color to be red 
when values entered must be black

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change an input's HTML5 placeholder color with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css)

Comment: thank you  i tried it but it applies color to a single box and when i type values in that textbox it also changes to red  . i have combination of textbox and combobox inside a popup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col col-50">
        <input type="number" placeholder="Price Color" name="price" class="textbox" ng-model="Price" ng-class="{'placeholder': Price == 'Price Color'}" required>
    </div>    
    <div class="col col-50">
        <input type="number" placeholder="Discount Color" class="textbox" ng-model="discount"  ng-class="{'placeholder': discount== 'Discount Color'}">
    </div>    
</div>
```

And set 'placeholder' class for the color you want.
Obviously put the values of 'Discount Color' and 'Price Color' in some variable

Comment: i am new to programming i dont know about ng-class. is there any possibility only using css

Comment: ngClass adds a class to the element when a condition is met, pretty straight-forward. So the 'placeholder' will be added to the input only when rice == 'Price Color' is true.

Try and provide a fiddle if you need more help